# Jmeter to test a java main class

Tags: testing, jmeter, beanshell

I have a java jar file which contains a main class and a batch file to execute the jar file. So I would like to call with Jmeter 3 the batch file to execute the java main class.

Could some one can help me, because it's my first time to use Jmeter? I have tried to use beanshell, but no success.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least 3 options:

1. Use [OS Process Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) to call the batch file by means of your operating system
2. Use [JSR223 Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) to do the same, this approach will be cross-platform. The syntax is very simple, it will be just path to your script followed by `.execute()`, i.e.

   ```
   'jmeter.bat'.execute()
   ```
3. Add your .jar to [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) and call your class "main" method using:

   - aforementioned JSR223 Sampler
   - [JUnit Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JUnit_Request) sampler
   - [Java Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request) sampler